# Why do I get TRUE when checking if a character value is greater than a number?

Tags: r

Can someone explain to me what's going on here? Specifically:

- Why do I get a TRUE in the first place for the first case?
- Why does it switch to FALSE when comparing with "10"?

---

```
"9" > 2
# [1] TRUE

"10" > 2
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: They are compared as strings. `"9" > "2"`, `"10" > "2"` is FALSE because it compares `"1" > "2"`

Comment: Some related posts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932015/why-true-true-is-true-in-r/14932160 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005295/why-does-one-2-equal-false-in-r

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hierarchy for coercion is: logical < integer < numeric < character.  So in both cases, the numeric is coerced to character.  Characters get "sorted" position by position in ASCII order.  So `"9"` is greater than `"2"` but `"10"` is less than `"2"` because `"1"` is less than `"2"`.